# How to modify the imperia cms user interface?

Tags: user-interface, content-management-system, updates

How can the user interface of an **imperia 9** CMS be changed without 
loosing the changes with the next update or hotfix?

Comment: I know that there is nearly no (public) documentation for it, so I added it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rather safe way to do it.

Say *C:/imperia/dev/* is the path of your **imperia development system**, 
then you find the imperia default views
in *C:/imperia/dev/site/view/imperia*. You can create your 
own views in a directory next to it *C:/imperia/dev/site/view/mycustomviews*.

Now copy a view from the */view/imperia* tree to your 
 */view/mycustomviews* tree, keeping the structure and filename and change the content to your needs.

To let imperia know how to find your views, you have to define your your view-template directory 
in the system configuration file *system.conf*.

```
"VIEW_TEMPLATE_DIRS" = "C:/imperia/dev/site/view/siau/mycustomviews"
```

#### updates

This way is rather safe, because you do **not** change your default. That's important. Don't touch 
the files in *C:/imperia/dev/site/view/imperia*. You may loose your changes with
the next update.

But you should know that you may do not participate in fixes or changes concering this view. Let's think of a 
optimization to the default view (may be to the behavior in a current browser). With your own view you overlay 
the default and you do **not** get the changes in your GUI.

#### development

While developing your new views you should add the following lines to your *system.conf*:

```
"IMPVIEW_ERRORS" = "HTML,JS,STDERR"
"IMPVIEW_DEVTOOLS" = "1"     
"IMPVIEW_CACHE_POLICY" = "timestamp"
```

With *IMPVIEW_ERRORS* you can controll where the view errors are displayed.

*IMPVIEW_DEVTOOLS* adds some develop methods to your views (e.g. dump).

And with *IMPVIEW_CACHE_POLICY* set to *timestamp* your views will no longer be cached. Thats great 
for development, but you should remove it for productive usage. (The other two as well.)

If something went wrong and you get unecpected results comment the *VIEW_TEMPLATE_DIRS* line. Then you
get back the default views and you can try to reproduce the problem.